# Given bifunctor $F$, what is the name of the functor with switched arguments?

Tags: notation, category-theory, terminology

Sorry for the unspecific title. Here the actual question:

Given categories $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$, let $S$ be the canonical functor $\mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$.

Given a bifunctor $F : \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{C}$, is there an established name or notation for:

- the functor $F\circ S : \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{C}$
- the "induced" functor $\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{C}^\mathcal{A}$ (which I would call the exponential transpose of $F\circ S$, but that is unsatisfactory)

A partial answer will suffice.

Comment: I suggest to name it the opposite bifunctor, because for relations we do this. But of course this is not "established".

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg and then the other functor should be the opposite exponential transpose? If I don't find anything else, I guess I'll stick with this. Thanks.

Comment: Passing from $\mathcal B \times \mathcal A \to \mathcal C$ to $\mathcal B \to \mathcal C^{\mathcal A}$ is often called _currying_.

Comment: @Pece I know, but that is not what I'm asking for. I want a name in terms of the functor $F$